# how to select rows where for a column there are two rows one with null and another with non-null value then select only row with non-null value

Tags: oracle

```
Column A      Column B

117220177     BOOK9488
117220177     NULL
14061         NULL
```

Oracle query for selecting rows:

When Column B has two rows corresponding to column A then pick row with non-null value in Column B. When there is only one row then pick irrespective of value in Column B

Expected Output:

```
Column A      Column B

117220177     BOOK9488
14061         NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Column_A, MAX(Column_B) Column_B
FROM test
GROUP BY Column_A;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0005b690d3339a6a3c378ebc9e939d0)